# Como desativar o CTRL+C em batch?

Tags: script, batch, powershell, vbs

É possível desativar o comando CTRL+C em batch?

Answer (score 1):

Outra opção seria um script como o abaixo, adapte-o para suas necessidades:

Esse arquivo de lote não pode ser cancelado por Ctrl-C e, se for cancelado por Ctrl-Break, a janela cmd.exe será fechada.

```
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1" equ "NonCancelable" goto NonCancelable
start "" /B cmd /C "%~F0" NonCancelable
exit

:NonCancelable
echo You can NOT cancel me!
echo/
set "var="
set /P "var=Enter password (enter Exit to end): "
if /I "%var%" neq "exit" goto :NonCancelable
echo Terminating non cancelable...
pause
exit
```

Original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36953316/935330

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu comentário!

Answer (score 0):

> Sim e Não !
>
> por padrão, no **Batch** não há como barrar o **Ctrl+C** porém é possível
>   desativar essas teclas com algum *"utilitário"* externo, escrito em uma
>   linguagem de programação, porém eu não conheço nenhum, mas é possível caso exista algum.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu comentário!

Answer (score 0):

No windows 10 é possível alterando as propriedades, primeiro abra o prompt em modo Administrador, depois clique com o direito no titulo do prompt e vá em propriedades e desabilite a opção para ctrl:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>(fonte: [merabheja.com](https://merabheja.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/editOptions.jpg))</sub>

Comment: mas aí não vai funcionar mais nenhum atalho de Ctrl, correto?
a não ser que essa máquina seja um servidor e não seja necessário usar atalhos, essa opção e boa.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu comentário!